# Apply an action to each item in a selection in turn?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

If you use an Illustrator action on a selection, it applies it to that selection as a whole.

Illustrator actions can be applied as 'batches', but this means batches of files, not batches of objects.

Is there a way to apply an action to each object in turn (like Transform Each does), not the whole selection?

Answer (score 2):

With scripting yes. Modified the AI scripting docs:

```
var docSelected = app.activeDocument.selection;
if ( docSelected.length > 0 ) {
    if ( docSelected.length > 0 ) {
        for ( i = 0; i < docSelected.length; i++ ) {
            docSelected[i].selected = false;
            //Do Something to docSelected[i]
        }
    } else {
        docSelected.selected = false;
        //Do Something to docSelected[i]
    }
} else {
    alert( "Please select one or more art objects" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var docSelected = app.activeDocument.selection;
if ( docSelected.length > 0 ) {
        var actionName = prompt("Which action do you want to run?", "");
        var set = prompt("Which set is your action in?", "Default Actions");
    for ( i = 0; i < docSelected.length; i++ ) {
        docSelected[i].selected = false;
    }
    app.activeDocument.selection = null;
    for ( i = 0; i < docSelected.length; i++ ) {
        docSelected[i].selected = true;
        app.doScript(actionName, set)
        docSelected[i].selected = false;
        app.activeDocument.selection = null;
    }
} else {
    alert( "Please select one or more art objects" );
}
```